# How to remove an item from a nested object redux state

Tags: redux, nested, immutability, reducers, nested-object

```
{thisObject : [ 0: {property1: true,property2: 4},

1: {property3: 'hello',

property4: 'goodbye'},

2: {property5: 'imagine there are 2000 of these objects and each object has 30-50 properties',

property6: 'How in the world does one remove a specific object, along with the id, for example the object corresponding to id number 1'}

]}
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to immutability remove one of the ids from the state. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Json you've provided is malformed. Should it be something like `{thisObject: [{id: 0, properties: {property1: true, property2: 4}}, {id: 1, properties: {property3: 'hello', property4: 'goodbye'}}]}` or like this `{thisObject: [{property1: true, property2: 4}, {property3: 'hello', property4: 'goodbye'}]}` ?

Answer (score 0):

I often recommend that data be stored in key-value objects keyed by id because those are a lot easier to work with than arrays.  But in this case - removing an item matching a given id - it's actually pretty easy with arrays because [`array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a new array so it's safe to use.

Assuming `thisObject` is a property of `state` and `id` is the id to remove:

```
return {
  ...state,
  thisObject: state.thisObject.filter( obj => obj.id !== id ),
}
```